# Is the destructor of a local object inside a loop guaranteed to be called before the next iteration?

Tags: c++, destructor

When I have a loop and inside this loop create a new stack variable (not allocating it on the heap and variable holding it declared inside the loop body), is the destructor of this object guaranteed to be called before the next iteration starts, or might loop unrolling by the compiler change something about that?

Comment: Loop unrolling *per se* won't change the order of execution. However, loop ***parallelization*** could do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ - If an object is declared in a loop, is its destructor called at the end of the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388108/c-if-an-object-is-declared-in-a-loop-is-its-destructor-called-at-the-end-of)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `n4800`:

§6.3.3 **Block Scope**:

> A name declared in a block (8.3) is local to that block; it has block scope. Its potential scope begins at its
>   point of declaration (6.3.2) and ends at the end of its block. A variable declared at block scope is a local
>   variable.

§10.3.6 **Destructors**:

> A destructor is invoked implicitly [...] when the block in which an object is
>   created exits (8.7)

§4.1.1 **Abstract machine**:

> This provision is sometimes called the “as-if” rule, because an implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this
>   document as long as the result is as if the requirement had been obeyed, **as far as can be determined from the observable
>   behavior of the program**.

*[Emphasis mine]*

So, yes. Your variable goes out of scope at the end of the loop (which is a block) and hence its destructor is called *as far as anyone observing the behavior of the program can tell*.

Comment: Nothing in there about WHEN the destructor is called.

Comment: Compilers are allowed to reorder operations that don't impact function. The destructor could be called halfway through the next loop.

Comment: @stark What allows them to do this is the as-if rule. The standard only specifies behavior of the abstract machine. Not sure if it's necessary to go into all that detail in answers here.

Comment: question is if the standard specifies that the destructor is called immediately before the next loop starts or not. If it's not specified, then I guess the compiler would be allowed to do it without violating the as-if rule, since it's still behaving as defined, no?

Comment: @stark This is, IMO, irrelevant to the question. You may as well say that destructors may be inlined, and therefore not `call`ed at all. Or, if they effectively (as-if rule) do nothing, there may be no assembly for such destructors generated.

Comment: Suppose the destructor writes to cout. What in the standard guarantees when that happens?

Comment: @stark See [What exactly is the “as-if” rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15718262/580083).

Comment: The as-if rule only applies to defined operations. I'm asking where this is defined.

Comment: @stark Where is defined _what_? Note that this discussion is off-topic to the question. You may ask another separate question about this problem.

Comment: It's exactly on topic actually. If it's not clearly defined when the destructor gets called, then the 'as-if' rule can't be used to explain why loop unrolling for example couldn't change the order of things that are happening.

Comment: @user1282931 I cannot quote the standard (although I am sure the standard is quite clear on the matter), but destructors getting called deterministically is what makes C++ C++. Do you really doubt that it is possible to be sure when a destructor is called?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Added quotes from the standard.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. It's easier to visualize when you consider the "blocks" in which you declare a variable, i.e. between which pair of braces. The loop is a block in itself, and when it reaches the closing bracket, before the next iteration, all destructors of automatic storage variables declared in the loop are called.

> might loop unrolling by the compiler change something about that?

As a rule of thumb don't think about what the compiler will optimize, because it still needs to guarantee the behaviour of your program, no matter what it does to optimize it. In that case, loop unrolling won't change anything to that effect if it happens.

Comment: +1 for the rule of thumb, when writing code one should not worry about compiler internals. Was going to add something in the same spirit to my answer, but now its already there

Comment: copy-elision and RVO change the program behavior, isn't it?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès They can potentially, however, the standard allows them too per `[class.copy.elision] `

Comment: Not just _pair of braces_. You can write `for(...) X x{};` and the `x` object will be constructed+destructed in each iteration. [Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0x9fc2u4a8AVKazQ). A relevant Standard section is [stmt.iter/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.iter#2).

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica As per §9.5.2 `[stmt.iter]` it's purely equivalent (emphasis mine): "If the substatement in an iteration-statement is a single statement and not a compound-statement, **it is as if it was rewritten to be a compound-statement containing the original statement.**". In essence, with or without the braces for a single statement means exactly the same thing and the braces are implicit. I omitted it for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

The destructor is called for every iteration. Thus in some cases it’s faster to declare a variable **outside** the loop instead of in the loop.
Assuming the following case:

```
std::string temp;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    temp = arr[i];
    doSomething(temp);
}
```

The destructor is not called when using the loop is executed. It just overrides `temp`.

But if you use `std::string temp = arr[i]` the constructor and destructor is called for each iteration. 
I think this adds a bit runtime in case you have a loop that is executed very often.

Comment: note that destructors getting called or not is not just a question of performance. When you have a RAII type, you specifically want the destructor to be called on every iteration

Comment: not sure that's true. Doesn't the destructor of the contents 'temp' is holding from the previous iteration get called right when temp gets reassigned with the new value?

Comment: I am not a 100% sure either. Correct my answer if you found something wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

The destructor is called before the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

Of course dtor is called at the end of the iteration and loop unrolling should not modify this behavior, as any other optimisation (an optimisation should not modify the program behavior), except some kind of RVO and alike which may eliminate some semantically spurious object creations.